# How to do multiple `typedef` for different types?

Tags: c++

Is there any way to do multiple `typedef` for different types ?

Example, instead of doing this

```
typedef unsigned char UBYTE;
typedef signed char SBYTE;
typedef unsigned short int UWORD;
typedef signed short int SWORD;
```

I could do *something like this*

```
typedef {
    unsigned char UBYTE;
    signed char SBYTE;
    unsigned short int UWORD;
    signed short int SWORD;
}
```

Comment: What possible gain would that give apart from saving text in your source code???

Comment: OT: Use "using" instead of "typedef" if C++11 or higher avaible

Comment: @barak note that he's not saving on lines, they increase from 4 to 6

Comment: @KarstenKoop: Lines - no, characters - yes... Nevertheless, what's the point?

Comment: @barakmanos I don't want to save anything. I just feel that the code will be leaner (in my point of view) and the user defined types could be centralized.

Comment: @IlDivinCodino: Leaner??? The code will look practically the same IMO.

Comment: @barakmanos (in my point of view)